# npm start runs listing directory in browser, not index.js

Tags: javascript, webpack-dev-server, babeljs

I setup tooling for a webpack/babel development server. When I run "npm start" from the command line, it displays the directory in my browser, not index.js. I'm just learning this; it's my first time creating a starter pack like this. My package.json file is below:

```
{
"name": "me_app",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "ME React-Redux Pump Builder",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
   "start": "node ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev server.js",
   "test": "mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --require ./test/test_helper.js --recursive ./test",
   "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch"
 },
 "author": "Daniel Crain",
 "license": "ISC",
 "directories": {
   "lib": "lib"
 },
 "dependencies": {
   "npm": "^6.4.1"
 },
 "devDependencies": {
   "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
   "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
   "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
   "babel-loader": "^8.0.2",
   "react": "^16.5.0",
   "react-dom": "^16.5.0",
   "webpack": "^4.17.2",
   "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0",
   "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.8"
 },
 "repository": {
   "type": "git",
   "url": "git+https://github.com/bluevision/React-Redux-Product- Configurator.git"
 },
 "bugs": {
   "url": "https://github.com/bluevision/React-Redux-Product- 
Configurator/issues"
 },
 "homepage": "https://github.com/bluevision/React-Redux-Product- 
 Configurator#readme"
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you list the files and directory structure of your project, would help to understand the exact problem, but as far as I know When you run `npm start` it will run your start command in your script object in package.json :

```
   "start": "node ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev server.js",
```

And here the script is expecting to listen to a file named `server.js` not `index.js`

So Try to rename the file name or edit the name in your package.json.

Comment: Actually, it's supposed to start webpack-dev-server.js, not index.js or server.js. Somehow the dash was removed when posting this. The webpack dev server is supposed to run the index.js file.